# How do I use conditional formatting to obtain absolute value of the top 10% in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, percentile

I am trying to find the top 10% of values of a specified range in excel. My negative values are not considered "lower" than my positive values. What I mean by that is these are difference values so even a large negative value could still be considered in the top 10%.

I tried to apply this formula in the conditional formatting but it seems to highlight my whole range of values instead of just the top 10%.

```
=ABS(B37)>=PERCENTILE(ABS($B$37:$S$67),0.10)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show some values and which you'd expect to be in the top 10%?

Comment: For the range of values, the ones that are in the top 10% that are positive are for example 0.0015,0.0008,0.0007,0.0006 but there are also values like -0.0008 which should also be included that are not when you do the standard built in conditional formatting for top 10%.

Comment: try changing `0.1` to `0.9`?

Comment: I think this worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As also pointed out in the comments, your current formula gives you the *top 90%* so change `0.1` to `0.9` to get the *top 10%*

```
=ABS(B37)>=PERCENTILE(ABS($B$37:$S$67),0.9)
```